# The green searcher

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Sir, I have a great advantage in puzzle codes.
>   The green searcher submitted invalid endeavors.
>   Was it the solution?
>   Time eluded so easily many.
>   The day fanatics get to grandly celebrate: March ?????

What am I?

Comment: Excellent puzzle! Maybe it should be tagged enigmatic-puzzle instead of riddle, since it's not *actually* a riddle but only looks like one.

Comment: @Gamow - Another [example](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Rec/rec.puzzles/2006-01/msg00123.html) with just a few different words. But +1 for a good puzzle anyway.

Comment: @Gamow - Maybe Haobin knows? I am guessing that "green searcher" was a user name of a person who was associated with the original puzzle, but now there is no context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer will

> either be a word with 0 letters (the empty word)
>  or perhaps a word with 10 letters.

The explanation:

> **314159265**: Sir, I have a great advantage in puzzle codes.
>   **358979**:  The green searcher submitted invalid endeavors.
>   **3238**: Was it the solution?
>   **46264**: Time eluded so easily many.
>   **338327950**: The day fanatics get to grandly celebrate: March ?????

These numbers

> count the number of letters in the words of the "poem",
>  and they coincide with the first few digits of 
>  $\pi\approx3.14159265358979323846264338327950$
>
>  Since today is March 14 (the famous "[Pi Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day)"),
>  the intended answer should be the ten-letter word **fourteenth**.

Final comment:

> I have just read an article about Pi-Day, that mentioned the following classic pi-memorization sentence (which might be the root of the riddle):
>
>  Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling
>  In mystic force and magic spelling,
>  Celestial sprites elucidate
>  All my own striving can't relate.
>  Or locate they who can cogitate
>  And so finally terminate. Finis.

Comment: I'm really mad at that poem, the meter is awful.