# Before the Ides of March

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> If I lost a leg I'd be twice the size
>   When grown up I cause many multiplies
>   Maybe mistaken for a fifth in Rome
>   Or for twelve thirteenths in a modern home

What am I?

Comment: Happy (British) Pie Week.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> $\pi$

If I lost a leg I'd be twice the size

> By removing one vertical line from $\pi$ we get $\tau$, which is a standard mathematical notation for $2\pi$; see for example the links
>  http://www.thepimanifesto.com/  and
>  https://xkcd.com/1292/

When grown up I cause many multiplies

> $\prod$ is used as symbol for products in mathematical equations.

Maybe mistaken for a fifth in Rome

> Aicient Greek (not sure what this has to do with Rome) notation for 5 was something that resembles as PI. . Thanks to [Jan Ivan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49999/before-the-ides-of-march/50000?noredirect=1#comment153034_50000)

Or for twelve thirteenths in a modern home

> I got nothing here. Still looking for something that matches.

Bonus (Before the Ides of March)

> Happy Pi day. March 14. The Ides of March was March 15th in Rome.

Comment: rome 5 is proly just = V, but
greek ancient 5 = Π

Comment: Line 2: In mathematics, the capital-pi is used to denote products (in the same way as the capital-sigma is used to denote summations)

Comment: @Gamow. It was so obvious and I missed it. Thanks

Comment: Two years ago I solved another puzzle in this spirit: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10264/the-green-searcher

Comment: @Gamow. I see your move, and answer with this move: http://tauday.com/tau-digits

Comment: @Gamow, Also, from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi "In 1958 Albert Eagle proposed replacing π by τ (tau), where τ = π/2, to simplify formulas. However, no other authors are known to use τ in this way. Some people use a different value, τ = 6.283185... = 2π ...."

Comment: A year ago, a [relatively easy matchstick puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/ummm-what-day-was-it-a-matchstick-puzzle). Happy pi day everyone :)

Comment: Marius has it. Lines 3 & 4 are based on the defining formula of the answer. Thx @Gamow too.

Comment: Lines 3 & 4 use the formula pi = C/D

Comment: @Marius - you have the answer - to finish can use Roman and Hex for lines 3&4

Comment: @Marius - this would be a perfect day to finish last two lines, use Roman and hexadecimals.

Comment: @Tom Sorry, but I have no idea.

Comment: @Marius, it's just, Line 3) C = 100 / D = 500, Line 4) C = 12 / D = 13 (computer hex)