# I'm more than my brother but have less

Tags: riddle

> We are two brothers
>   bounded by a circle
>   I'm his double
>   but he has twice more legs than me

What are we?

Comment: This is my first riddle, and if anything should be unclear or two broad, I'd like to apologize for that in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is a play on something around

> pi ($\pi$) and tau ($\tau$)  both circle ratios.

I'm his double but he has twice more legs than me

> $\tau = 2\pi$ but $\pi$ has twice the number of legs of $\tau$.

Comment: That was even faster than I'm allowed to accept it

Comment: Thanks HerrSerker! I was fortunate as once asked [Before the Ides of March](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49999/before-the-ides-of-march)